# git log from a tag/branch/hash knowing that the remote is not origin

Tags: git

My project is named **main_project**. It's a [git](/questions/tagged/git) project.
The remote alias is **origin**.

Say this my [git](/questions/tagged/git) history:

```
* aaaaa (tag: 1.5.0, branch: master, develop)
* bbbbb (tag: 1.4.0)
* ccccc
|\
* \ ddddd (tag: 1.3.0)
|  * eeeee (tag: 1.2.13)
....
```

When I want to see my history from a specific ref (tag, branch or a hash)

```
$ git log 1.4.0 # or git log bbbbb

* bbbbb (tag: 1.4.0)
* ccccc
|\
* \ ddddd (tag: 1.3.0)
|  * eeeee (tag: 1.2.13)
....
```

This works.

The problem is when I added a new remote alias of another project **subproject**.

```
 git remote add subproject gituser@gitlab.com:company_name/subproject.git
 git fetch subproject # works well and do download the remote
```

When I want to show the whole history of only **subproject** I can thanks to :

```
git log --remotes=subproject
```

When I want it to start from a specific commit, it simply does not work and displays the whole history of the remote **subproject**. And below is what I've tried:

```
git log --remotes=subproject 6.10.4 # 6.10.4 is a tag of subproject git
```

How to display the [git](/questions/tagged/git) history of a specific remote other than **origin** from a specific ref (tag, branch or hash)?

```
$git --version
git version 2.11.1
```

**UPDATE**

One last thing, I just noticed that even with origin it does work when `--remotes` option is given. In other words, these three commands output the exact same thing

```
 git log --remotes=origin
 git log --remotes=origin some_valid_tag
 git log
```

When I remove `--remotes` option, I get what I want:

```
 git log some_valid_tag # History starting from some_valid_tag
```

Comment: What is git version you are using? What happens if you issue this command  that "does not work"? What happens after `git fetch subproject` - are any refs downloaded?

Comment: @JustMe thanks, I updated my question

Comment: Can't reproduce. I've built your git version and `/tmp/git/git log --remotes=subproject sometag` yields proper results. Can you reproduce that on some github or open project?

Comment: @JustMe humm...that's strange, `git log --remotes=subproject sometag` does displaythe git history starting from `sometag`? One last thing, I just noticed that even with origin it does work when `--remotes` option is given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works when you run:

```
git log some_valid_tag
```

is that `git log` doesn't do what you're thinking it does. :-)

What `git log` does is show commits.  You must tell it which commit(s) to start from:

```
git log HEAD
```

means to start from the commit that is identified by `HEAD`, for instance, and:

```
git log some_valid_tag
```

means to start from the commit that is identified by `some_valid_tag`.  Using:

```
git log HEAD some_valid_tag
```

means to start from *both* of these commits, and:

```
git log --remotes=abc
```

means to start from *every commit identified by every `abc/*` name*.

There are several interesting complications here.  We need to think about what "start from" *means*.  We need to consider what it means to "start from" more than one commit *at the same time*.  Relatedly, since Git is showing one commit at a time—one per line with `--oneline`—it must pick some *order* for showing two or more commits.  And, we need to think about what it means to show a commit.  The last is the easiest (well, initially anyway) and is mostly, though not completely, separate from the rest, so let's tackle it first.

#### Showing a commit

When `git log` shows a commit, it can show it in a bunch of different ways.  These are mostly controlled by the `--pretty=format` directives.  There are a bunch of built-in formats.  The most interesting three, in my opinion, are `oneline`, `medium` (the default), and `full`/`fuller`.  There are several more named formats, and if you don't like any of those, you can build your own using format directives (percent signs followed by, generally, letters).

The `--oneline` option is short for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`.  This is useful for showing as many commits as possible per page.  Adding `--graph` tells Git to draw an ASCII-art graph of the part of the commit graph being shown, and has a very strong side effect on the *order* in which commits are displayed.  **Adding `--decorate`, or setting `log.decorate` to `true`, makes Git add the `(tag: 1.5.0, master, develop)` annotations to specific commits.  Note that this has little to do with the set of starting commits: these decorations are added whenever the tag or branch or other name points to that commit and the commit is being shown.**  That's why `git log some_valid_tag` works for your case: you're starting from the tagged commit, and the `--decorate` option or equivalent is adding *all* the decorations that identify this particular commit, *regardless of what you're using as starting points.*

Note that adding the `-p` option shows each commit as a patch.  It does this by diffing (as in `git diff`) that commit against its parent commit.  But if that commit is itself a *merge commit*, with two or more parents, which commit should `git log` choose for this diff?  Git's default answer for `git log` is: *don't* choose; don't show a diff at all.  (Git's answer for `git show` is different: choose *all* the parents and show a *combined diff*.  You can make `git log` show a combined diff using `--cc`.  Combined diffs are a bit odd and don't necessarily show what people think they show, at first.)

#### Walking the commit graph

This part is especially tricky.  If you're new to Git and graph theory, you might start with [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), which will introduce you to the idea of graph-walking and [reachability](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graph-theory/reachability.html).

In general, though, Git needs to linearize a graph.  It does this by "walking through" each commit, one at a time.  Most commits have exactly one parent commit, which makes this easy: we're looking at one particular commit, so we show that commit.  Then we move to that commit's (single) parent, and now we're looking at one commit again.  So we show it and move to its parent, and so on.

That's fine if you have just *one* starting point.  But what if you have two or more?  We have to pick one to show, then show it, and then maybe show it's parent or maybe show the other one.  We also have a problem at each merge commit, which has at least two parents to show.  Which parent should we show first?  What about that parent's parent, and so on?  Git's answer to this problem is to use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

This priority queue lets you add multiple items—multiple commits, in our case—to your queue, then pull out the "most important" one first and work on it.  If you give `git log` three starting points, for instance, it simply drops all three into the priority queue, then pulls out the first one to show.  Having shown that commit, it drops that commit's parent or parents into the priority queue.  It's now ready to pull another (single) commit from the queue and show it; this puts that commit's parent or parents into the queue.  Note that putting someone—some parent commit—into the queue, if they are already in the queue, has no effect, unless it is to change their priority.

The default priority order for Git commits is their committer time-stamp (note that this is separate from their author time-stamp, which is the only one shown by default).  The commit with the highest committer time-stamp has the highest priority.  That way, as long as the dates are right—this is a pretty strong condition, as computer dates are all too often *wrong*—you see commits in the reverse of the order they were added to the repository.

Adding `--graph` has the side effect of adding `--topo-order`, which changes the priorities fairly radically.  When using `--graph`, any child always has higher priority than its parent, so that if we're walking two "lines" in a graph "at the same time", the parent commit comes out at the bottom, where the lines rejoin.  (Git offers `--date-order` to alter the implied `--topo-order`; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for the details.)

#### Putting it all together

Now that we have all the concepts lined up, here's the overall answer:

- `git log --remotes=subproject` adds every `subproject/*`-identified commit to the initial priority queue contents.
- Using a tag name adds the tagged commit to the priority queue.
- Omitting everything uses `HEAD` as the (single) starting commit in the priority queue.
- As Git shows you commits, one at a time as they are taken out of the priority queue, it can draw a graph (`--graph`) and/or decorate them with labels telling you which name(s) point to the commits.  This happens regardless of which commits you choose as starting-points.
- Before adding commits to the queue, `git log` checks whether they are reachable from "stopping point" arguments such as `^name` (remember that `origin/master..master` "means" `master ^origin/master`).  If so, Git simply doesn't add the commit.
- At merge commits, `git log` adds all parents of the merge commit to the queue, unless you use `--first-parent`, in which case it adds only the *first* parent of the merge to the queue.

These rules will get you most of the way through how `git log` works (the remaining hard part is what Git calls "history simplification").